# How do I trace SQL Server Failure Audit events?

Tags: sql-server

I recently took over management of a Windows 2003 server. The application log is being filled up with messages like these:

```
Event Type: Failure Audit
Event Source: MSSQLSERVER
Event Category: (4)
Event ID: 18456
Date:  3/5/2010
Time:  4:00:30 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: FAIROAKS1
Description:
Login failed for user 'administrator'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Data:
0000: 18 48 00 00 0e 00 00 00   .H......
0008: 0a 00 00 00 46 00 41 00   ....F.A.
0010: 49 00 52 00 4f 00 41 00   I.R.O.A.
0018: 4b 00 53 00 31 00 00 00   K.S.1...
0020: 07 00 00 00 6d 00 61 00   ....m.a.
0028: 73 00 74 00 65 00 72 00   s.t.e.r.
0030: 00 00                     ..      

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

I'd like to figure out what program is causing these. Is there a way to trace and find out which process is causing these errors?

Comment: you would likely gt more responses by asking this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks to people who looked at this and edited it for clarity. I'm going to take the brute force approach and just shut down services until the messages stop.....  @KM: thanks for the suggestion; if my brute force approach fails I'll follow up on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by some account not being able to log to the SQL Server instance installed on that server.

The message above means there is a SQL login (not Windows Auth) called "administrator" that is not set up in sys.server_principals or the password used is incorrect.

Now, if you run SQL profiler then you should be able to trap the connection attempt including HostName and Application name. [Audit Login Failed Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187862.aspx) is a good starting point.

Potentially, this is a serious issue: it could be an attack, of a failed monitor attempt. But it's nice you can shut-down your SQL Server instance and no-one notices ... :-)

Comment: The SQL Profiler...that is what I need :)  Thanks!